# Table data width wont apply

Tags: html, css, web

Right guys coding my first website and hitting a few bumps along the way. Any help is really appreciated. Ok so I have been trying to style my table (acting as a navigation bar) so that the 5 s are of equal width. I have set the table width to 100% and each of the 5 tds to 20%. However the width property won't apply. So then I tried it with different widths but none are applying. Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/> 
<title>First Website</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <section class="header">

        <header>
<a href=""><img src="Cantpostimagehere"/></a>
</header>

        </section>

        <section class="navbar">

        <nav>

            <table>

                <tr>

                    <td><a href="">About Me</a></td>

                    <td><a href="">Funny stuff</a></td>

                    <td><a href="">Home</a></td>

                    <td><a href="">Cool Pictures</a></td>

                    <td><a href="">Contact me</a></td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </nav>

        </section>

        <section class="main">

            <img src="Cantpostimagehere"/>

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.header img{

    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;

    width:50%;

    padding:0 0 5px 0;

}
.navbar td{
text-align:center;
    width:20%;

}

.navbar a:link{

    color:gray;

    text-decoration:none;

}

.navbar a:visited{

    color:gray;

    text-decoration:none;

}

.navbar a:hover{

    color:purple;

    font-weight:bolder;


}

.navbar table{

    position:fixed;
    width:100%;

    display:block;

    margin:0 auto;

    background-color:#cccccc;

    padding:10px;

    border:2px solid #999999;

}

.main img{
    width:90%;

    display:block;

    margin:10px auto;

    padding:2px;

    border:4px solid #999999;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `display:block` applied to your table, in order for the td to fill the space properly it's parent (table) needs to be set as `display:table`

Edited. Thanks @Oriol

Comment: The `<td>`s already act as table cells. But table cells of an anonymous table, which won't be as wide as the `<table>`